# Double Recursion in C language

Tags: c, recursion

Guys my tutor told me he'll put double recursion in the C programming exam. I've never heard of or imagined a recursion within a recursion before. Is it like a 2D array with a loop within a loop type of logic? Can you guys kindly help me out with the concept or an example? I failed to find anything on other websites.
Thanks!

EDiT: Update on what the double recursion means. Like a for loop within a for loop, the question was as follows;

Q) Print the pattern 1/1! + 2/2! + 3/3! + 4/4! + ... + n/n! and find numerator and denominator using recursion. How I did it was by obtaining a number of patterns from the user and passing it in the numerator's recursion where 'i' increase till 'n'. Then in the numerator recursion, the denominator recursion for factorial starts, so "rec=rec*i" until I <=n.
solution:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int numerator(int,int);
int denominator(int,int);
int main()
{
    int n=0, i=1;
    printf("Please enter the last number of your series : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    numerator(i,n);
}
numerator(i,n)
{
    int d=1;
    if (i<=n)
    {
        if (i==n)
        {
            printf(" %d/%d",i,denominator(d,i));
        }
        else
        {
            printf(" %d/%d +",i,denominator(d,i));
            i++;
            numerator(i,n);
        }
        
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
denominator(int d,int i)
{
    if (i==1)
    {
        return d;
    }
    else
    {
        d=d*i;
        i--;
        denominator(d,i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have never heard about it either. Maybe he was referring to [mutual recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion)?

Comment: Or maybe to **double recursive calls**, such as a tree-search function which makes two recursive calls to explore the two branches of a binary tree; or such as a bad fibonacci implementation which makes two recursive calls to fib(n-1) and fib(n-2).

Comment: Or if this is a theoretical class: [Theoretical Computer Science concept called "double recursion"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_recursion). But I highly doubt it, since this doesn't have much to do with a course on C programming.

Comment: Is that phrasing "a recursion within a recursion" by your tutor or you guessing? It seems to be nothing different than normal "recursion". Anyway, with "several StackOverflow users have not heard of double recursion" you should be fine to ask (without seeming clueless) your tutor for clarification or at least confirm/refute the guesses in comments above.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'd ask your tutor what they mean.

Comment: I suspect what it means is to use a recursive function for the summation of the terms (`1/1!`, `2/2!`, etc.) which in turn uses a recursion function for the calculation of the factorial in the denominator of each term (`1!`, `2!`, etc.). So the summation function, call it `fn(int n)`, has a recursive line `fn(n - 1)` to compute the sum up to that point and then adds to that sum `n / fd(n)` where the function `fd(int n)` computers the factorial for `n`. I tried this out and did a check with the first few numbers, 1 through 5, and results seem to agree with the Google calculator that Chrome has.

Answer (score 4):

"Double Recursion" is slang, as it is not a standard name of a particular kind of recursion.  Possible standard recursion terms it might be describing include:

1. Mutual Recursion, where `f(x) -> t(...) and t(x) -> f(...)` such that one recursive call enters the same function after going through a second function.  This is difficult for tool builders, because it means they need to do tracing analysis of function implementations to see if there are any loops.
2. A recursive call which takes as a parameter a second instance of the recursive call.  `f(x, f(x))` is an example, as is `f(f(x))` or any other nesting.
3. A recursive call which (due to the constraints of the question) is going to only require evaluation twice. `f(x) = x + f(x-1), (if x>0) or x (if x<=0)` is an example when `f(2)` is being evaulated.
4. A recursive call which is using the C type `double` - This is sort of a dumb possibility, but sometimes it's just a matter of poor word choice when a teacher tries to explain what's on the test without going into too many details.
5. A function might call itself twice as part of its recursion - This might look like `f(x) = f(x-1) + f(x-2)`

If you can, I would reach back to the teacher and ask for a non-test example of double recursion or which page in your textbook (if you are using one) where double recursion was discussed.  Good teachers are happy to help a student learn an item, even if it was covered in class before, during their office hours.  If it is a matter of using a different name for the kinds of recursion you know already, then you will quickly discover which kind of recursion is being discussed.

Comment: You missed one: 5. A function that may call itself twice directly before returning.

Comment: @IanAbbott I'll add it.  Thank you!